# How can Find all dependencies of an application?

Tags: dll, dllimport, portable-executable, dll-dependency

In a Portable-Exe ,there is possibilities to find the imported section ,and also all imported dll names (using import descriptor).Here Ex, One application Exe has many imported dlls(kernel32,advapi,user,comctl32....etc),Now i want to find all dependencies in that app exe(imported dlls)..give me the logic using recursive function calling..

Here ,Ex notepad.exe ,supposed having two dlls (advapi32,user32) ,i can fetch those dlls details ,i want to know imported dlls of advapi and user32 ....by the way of all dependencies...can u give the logic only ,its very helpful to me ....thanks

Comment: Yes. Go accept some answers (starting with this one :-P)

Comment: ok moran ,i dont know about it ,its my fault ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) can do this for you: It displays a tree of all dependencies and their dependencies.

[alt text http://img526.imageshack.us/img526/4175/depnotepad.png](http://img526.imageshack.us/img526/4175/depnotepad.png)

Answer (score 2):

Dependency Walker is a free utility that scans any 32-bit or 64-bit Windows module (exe, dll, ocx, sys, etc.) and builds a hierarchical tree diagram of all dependent modules.

For More info  - [depends.exe](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)